# Why date_histogram aggregation does not work as expected in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate-functions

I have the below index in elastic search. I want to have a nested aggregation. The first one must be based on day (The keys which are unique must be days). And the second aggregation must be based on the type of severity, which can be WARNING, CRITICAL or INFO.

```
PUT sepanta_index_stream_events
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "device_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "device_name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": true,
        "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
        }
      }
      ,
      "event_time": {
        "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||epoch_second||epoch_millis||strict_date_optional_time"
      },
      "coordinate": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      },
      "rule_name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
        }
      },
      "event_value": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "rule_id": {
        "type":"keyword"
      },
      "severity": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "end_event_time": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||epoch_second||epoch_millis||strict_date_optional_time"
      },
      "is_finished":{
        "type":"boolean"
      },
      "customer_id":
      {
        "type":"keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since I store the `event_time` based on `epoch_millis`, so I define the `gte`, and `lte` based on milliseconds. And also define the `timezone`, and `calendar_interval` in the below query.

```
GET /sepanta_index_stream_events/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "event_time": {
            "gte": "1688998002000",
            "lte": "1690294002000"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "events_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "event_time",
        "calendar_interval": "day",
        "time_zone": "Asia/Tehran",
        "format": "epoch_millis"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "severity_count": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "severity"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the problem is that in the result, I expected to have 15 buckets, but there are I think more than 100 buckets. Also there are duplicate days as you can see in the results, their difference is in their hour and minute only.

```
{
  "took" : 52,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "events_per_day" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "1689662581200000", #2023-07-18
          "key" : 1689662581200000,
          "doc_count" : 4
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "1689662667600000", #2023-07-18
          "key" : 1689662667600000,
          "doc_count" : 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "1689662754000000", #2023-07-18
          "key" : 1689662754000000,
          "doc_count" : 0
        },
...
{
          "key_as_string" : "1690293900600000", #2023-07-25
          "key" : 1690293900600000,
          "doc_count" : 229,
          "severity_count" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "WARNING",
                "doc_count" : 229
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "1690293987000000", #2023-07-25
          "key" : 1690293987000000,
          "doc_count" : 49,
          "severity_count" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "WARNING",
                "doc_count" : 49
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I can not figure out the reason that also why when I change the format of `key` to `yyyy-mm-dd`, the values become so large!?

```
{
  "took" : 486,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "events_per_day" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "+55513-04-12",
          "key" : 1689662575800000,
          "doc_count" : 4,
          "severity_count" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "WARNING",
                "doc_count" : 4
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "+55513-04-13",
          "key" : 1689662662200000,
          "doc_count" : 0,
          "severity_count" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [ ]
          }
        },
...
```